# How to use service name with underscore in kubenetes?

Tags: kubernetes

We used to choose `docker swarm` as container orchestration for our system. And we switched to `kubenetes` this year. We have a backend service which is visited by `http://web_api:10001`. Here is the `web_api.yml` we use to create the `Service` in `kubenetes`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web_api
  namespace: my-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: web_api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 10001
      targetPort: 10001
```

However, name `web_api` is not allowed in `Service`. My question is how can I still use `web_api` here? If we modify other services which visit `http://web_api:10001`, that would be a lot of work because we have too many services which depends on `http://web_api:10001`.

Anyone can give me an advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kubernetes, service names must adhere to DNS label standards, which means they must:

- Contain at most 63 characters.
- Contain only lowercase alphanumeric characters or '-'.
- Start with an alphanumeric character.
- End with an alphanumeric character.

From my point of view you have 2 options, Create a CNAME in your dns provider or use an ingress controller, Let me explain the last one.

The idea is to use Kubernetes Ingress to route traffic from a specific URL to your renamed service (web-api). This approach allows you to maintain the existing service URLs (http://web_api:10001) in your dependent services while complying with Kubernetes naming conventions.

### 1. Rename Your Service

First, rename your service to comply with DNS naming conventions. For example, change web_api to web-api in your service definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-api
  namespace: my-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: web-api
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 10001
      targetPort: 10001
```

### 2. Set Up an Ingress Controller

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
```

### 3. Create an Ingress Resource

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-api-ingress
  namespace: my-system
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "web_api.my-domain.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: web-api
            port:
              number: 10001
```

In this example, any traffic to web_api.my-domain.com is routed to the web-api service. You'll need to adjust the host to match your DNS setup or use path-based routing if that's more suitable.